# Json data how to get the contents PHP

Tags: php, json, api, paypal

I am trying to use the paypal developer SDK for PHP for the first time.  I have followed a tutorial on youtube all going well until I tried to execute it and the response I recieved was malformed_request JSON request doesn not map to API request.  How do I get the struscture and contents of the JSON object so I can investigate further?  please see code below error happens on the try.  I am developing in netbeans 7.4

```
<?PHP
//this is copied from this tutorial here on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BD1dOWIABe0
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
require '/../app/start.php';
$pTotal = 20.00;
$shipping = 1.00;
$Total = $pTotal + $shipping ;
$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
$item = new Item();
$item->setName("tieThisToSomething")
->setCurrency('GBP')
->setQuantity(1)
->setPrice($pTotal);
$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems($item); //I have removed square brackets from here []
$details = new Details();
$details->setShipping($shipping)
    ->setSubtotal($pTotal);
$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('GBP')
    ->setTotal($Total)
    ->setDetails($details);
$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
    ->setItemList($itemList)
    ->setDescription('Pay for all your santa fun')
    ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());//perhaps tie this to order number?

$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setCancelUrl(SITE_URL . '/pay.php?success=false')
         ->setReturnUrl(SITE_URL . '/pay.php?success=true'); 

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setPayer($payer)
    ->setTransactions($transaction)
    ->setIntent('sale')
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)   ; //should [] be needed here?

//try {
//    $payment->create($paypal);
//} catch (Exception $e) {
//    die($e);
//}

try {
   $payment->create($paypal);  //Error happens here!
} catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
  echo $ex->getCode(); // Prints the Error Code
  echo $ex->getData(); // Prints the detailed error message 
 die($ex);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
 die($ex);
}

$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
header("Location: {$approvalUrl}");
```

Comment: You pass in `$paypal`, but that doesn't appear to be a used variable? Also, by the looks of it, `setItems` call should be passed an array.

Comment: I did have set Items as an array using []however I got an error saying found '[' expected )

Comment: Then it sounds like you're on PHP 5.3 or under? Assuming so, wrap the item in an array e.g. `array($item)` instead.

Comment: I am 5.3.8 thanks will l try that.

Comment: same issue just reviewing $paypal

Comment: $paypal is set up in another file and contains info for logging into paypal.  This is working ok as I altered part of the key and the error changed to incorrect key.

Comment: setTransactions($transaction) should be setTransactions(array($transaction))

Answer (score 0):

Adding logging would definitely help you investigate the raw details of the message. Here is the link to add configurations to enable logging:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Adding-Configurations

Also, there are a lot of [sample codes](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/tree/master/sample) that could help you setup your code. Here is the one that shows creating ["Payment with PayPal"](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.php). You could infact run those locally by following [instructions here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Samples).